# Include comments in exported XML file

Tags: export, xml, comment

When exporting an `XMLObject` (using `Export`/`ExportString`), is there any way to include a `<!-- -->` comment somewhere near the beginning of the file?

Note that [it is not valid to put the comment as the very first line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196467/ok-to-put-comments-before-the-xml-declaration).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the construction `XMLObject["Comment"]["..."]`.  This is described in detail [in this tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/XML/tutorial/RepresentingXML.html).  For example...

```
ExportString[
  XMLElement["root", {}
  , { "\n"
    , XMLObject["Comment"][" hello "]
    , XMLElement["content", {}, {"content goes here"}]
    , "\n"
    }
  ]
, "XML"
]
```

... will generate this XML:

```
<root>
<!-- hello -->
<content>content goes here</content>
</root>
```

The documentation for [XMLObject](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/XMLObject.html) states that we can use this pattern to create various XML node types: declarations, comments, documents, doctypes, processing instructions and CDATA sections.  Here is an example that shows each type:

```
ExportString[
  XMLObject["Document"][
    { XMLObject["Declaration"]["Version"->"1.0","Encoding"->"UTF-8","Standalone"->"no"]
    , XMLObject["Doctype"]["zot", "Public"->"-//???//zot", "System"->"urn://zot.zot"]
    }
  , XMLElement["zot", {}
    , { "\n"
      , XMLObject["Comment"][" witty remark "]
      , XMLElement["content", {}, {"to be determined"}]
      , "\n"
      , XMLObject["CDATASection"]["&&&!<><>!"]
      , "\n"
      , XMLObject["ProcessingInstruction"]["disposition: discard"]
      }
    ]
  , {}
  ]
, "XML"
]
```

yielding:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no'?>
<!DOCTYPE zot PUBLIC '-//???//zot' 'urn://zot.zot'>
<zot>
<!-- witty remark -->
<content>to be determined</content>
<![CDATA[&&&!<><>!]]>
<?disposition: discard?>
</zot>
```